# How to install npm library (juice 9.1.0)?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I tried it in the way below.

Will I need to do anything else?

I am trying to install the library for the first time.
I need help..

https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice

1. package.json add

> "devDependencies": {
> "juice": "^9.1.0"
> }

---

2. npm install , npm run dev

> Failed to compile with 2 errors

ERROR  in ./node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/esm/index.js                                                                                                     friendly-errors 13:00:39

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (48:9)                                                                                                                                    friendly-errors 13:00:39
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  * They should probably be removed eventually.
|  */

> export * as ElementType from "domelementtype";
> | import { getFeed } from "domutils";
> | export { getFeed } from "domutils";

---

ERROR  in ./node_modules/parse5/dist/index.js                                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 13:00:39

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:9)                                                                                                                                     friendly-errors 13:00:39
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export { ERR as ErrorCodes } from './common/error-codes.js';
| /** @internal */

> export * as foreignContent from './common/foreign-content.js';
> | /** @internal */
> | export * as html from './common/html.js';